# Octave: Loaded package is not recognized

Tags: octave

I have installed package `image` via `pkg install -forge image` and after tons of warnings (I am using *clang* as a C compiler, yeah, I know...) it finished installing.

I then loaded the package with ordinary `pkg load image` and Octave did not complain. But when I typed `help viscircles` to get some help on the function, Octave behaved like there was no package `image`, meaning it returned

```
>> help viscircles
error: help: the 'viscircles' function belongs to the image package 
from Octave Forge but has not yet been implemented.

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
```

Now I executed the `pkg list` to see if the package was indeed installed and loaded and yes, it was (there was an asterisk next to `image` package, which indicates that the certain package is loaded).

I decided to unload all packages and so I did. Now, before loading `image` again, I executed `help viscircles` again, but this time I got the next error:

```
>> help viscircles
error: help: the 'viscircles' function belongs to the image package 
from Octave Forge which you have installed but not loaded.  To load the 
package, run 'pkg load image' from the Octave prompt.
```

Interesting... I loaded the package again and same problem as before. I also downloaded the package manually and reinstalled it, same problems.

And yes, I have Octave 4.0.2, the requirements for image 2.6.2 is version 4.0.0+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `viscircles` is on development versions of the image package only. It is not part of the current release, version 2.6.2 which you have installed.

The error message:

```
>> help viscircles
error: help: the 'viscircles' function belongs to the image package 
from Octave Forge which you have installed but not loaded.  To load the 
package, run 'pkg load image' from the Octave prompt.
```

means that the function is not part of Octave and if it is to exist at all, it will be on the image package. It doesn't mean that the image package will actually have it, only that it belongs to it.  The error message you get after loading the package:

```
>> help viscircles
error: help: the 'viscircles' function belongs to the image package 
from Octave Forge but has not yet been implemented.

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
```

tells you the issue.  The function `viscircles` is not implemented on that version of the package.

You can get it from the mercurial repository of the image package though at [75df28049249](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/raw-file/75df28049249/inst/viscircles.m). Not sure if it will work on Octave 4.0 though.